# Spring security login logout in html (not jsp)

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working on a project with angular.js on front end and spring mvc in backend. I have recently started using spring security.

I wanted to implement login logout functionality using spring security. But so far, all the tutorials and forums I have seen, uses jsp pages as custom login pages. But with angular, all pages are in html.

So, I am wondering that is it possible to use spring security in html pages ? If yes, then how ?

So far I have found out that it can be probably done using 'thymeleaf'. But is there any other way ?

Comment: As you are using angularjs, you can configure rest api using spring. That is, no view (neither jsp nor html) in your Spring project. Use `@RestController` and Spring security for stateless authentication.

Comment: Good idea ! I'll try that. It's just that I tried spring security on a non-angular sample application, so I started this way.